# Microsoft excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I run my macro, and it seems to be working fine until the last part it highlighted this error:

> Run-time error '1004'" Application-defined or object-defined error

```
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Impressions"), "Sum of Impressions", xlSum
```

Hope someone can enlighten this for me, thanks so much in advance!

Regards, 
Dexter

Answer (score 1):

The error is non-specific, but I suspect that your worksheet might be lacking objects named `PivotTable1` or it's missing a field called `Impressions`.